# Exception Handling issue with "message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, exception, memory-management

I have enabled NSZombie and i got the message as "message sent to deallocated instance", I know it is a memory management issue, but why my try catch or uncaught exception handling techniques work with Zombies, why aren't they caught in the catch braces, is there any way to stop my app from crashing at runtime, Any solution is appreciated in Advance Thanks

Comment: no code, no bug. No bug, no solution

Comment: the only proper way to stop your app from crashing is to fix your bugs, not hiding them.

Comment: There is apparently a problem that try/catch doesn't work right in some circumstances on the iOS 5 emulator.  It does reportedly work OK on the hardware, and I've not seen evidence of the problem on iOS 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to stop the app crashing at runtime :

Don't send messages to deallocated instances :)

More helpfully, instead of trying to hide a bug you should probably be concentrating more on finding its root cause, otherwise you have no idea what other side effects it's having on your app or what trouble it will cause in the future.

If you add some code and stack traces / console output to your question we can help find the problem.

Comment: well dude, can you tell me why try catch can't caught them, any link to read and understand the real concept :)

Comment: Because it's not an objective-c exception - no-one has thrown anything; you've accessed a memory location that your app isn't allowed to access and that's a much lower level problem so iOS will just end your app (with a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

Answer (score 1):

see this link for implementing try catch exception. I think you are implementing try catch in some wrong way....
[exception-handling-in-objective-c](http://www.quagnitia.com/iPhoneLearning/beginners/exception-handling-in-objective-c/)